# How to get a wireframe to have a "flat" edge instead of a "sharp" one?

Tags: wireframe

The title is confusing.
I have a wireframe I made
[image]

This wireframe has "sharp" edges

[image]

This is what I mean by "flat" edges. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

This could be a 1-segment Bevel, with original faces removed. This example makes the generation a little more procedural, using modifiers:

[image]

- Polyhedron
- *Bevel*: All: 1 segment, with material index set to 1
- A little GN modifier, deleting all faces with material index 0
- *Solidify*
- Another *Bevel*: By Angle: to hold shading, and Shade Smooth

[image]

---

Edit: (response to commentary)

Materials are assigned per-face; an object can have more than one material. The materials-per-object are held in a list. The Material Index is into that list.

[image]

The Bevel modifier doesn't offer to output a vertex-group 'generated vertices' or suchlike, but does offer to give a 'Material Index' to the generated faces. I've used that as a get-around. (Bottom of above illustration.)

A small Geometry Nodes modifier can delete faces, explicitly  selecting by `Material Index == 0`:

[image]

The rest of the modifier stack is unexceptional: a *Solidify*, and further *Bevel* on the resulting 3D sharply angled edges, to prevent mushy interpolation of vertex-normals across those by smooth shading, while allowing the interpolation between faces meeting at shallower angles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am new to Blender, so I had to open your file to figure some stuff out. I still need some help though. My questions: 
1. What is a material index? I think it's used for classifying different "layers".
2. I took a look at the node and while I can make some sense of it, I don't understand much of it. 
It would be great if you could explain it to me.
Thanks.

Comment: @SlightyBurntPorkChop .. hope the edit helps .. call back if not :) You should be able to apply the whole effect to new meshes by 1: Ctrl-L > Link Materials 2: Ctrl-L > Copy Modifiers 3: Object > Shade Smooth.

Comment: Thanks for clearing some things up. I understand that I need to seperate the new beveled faces in order to delete them with a geometry node. One last question, I'm not entirely sure why beveling after the solidify is necessary. I don't understand your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @SlightyBurntPorkChop  https://imgur.com/a/goxvbLW takes a shot  at explaining why you would want a second bevel to make smooth-shading look better.

Comment: Alr, I'll take a look at it.